# django cannot convert queryset to list to js array

Tags: javascript, django

Using Django I have a view which pulls a queryset and attempting to convert to a list as context to the template which then feeds through to javascript array however it's as if the queryset is not converting to a real list as javascript validation is not accepting the list and thus validation not working.

I have also created a normal list rather than from a queryset and works as I expect for my JS validation but everything I have tried in converting the queryset to a list the javascript just will not accept it to the array.

I have also tried to convert the list as json as well from what I read online and still not working.

I have tried my own for loop on the queryset to append to a new list but also done nothing.

Please see the following code:

**View (manual python list which works tried and tested)**

```
mylist= ['sid', 'john']
context = {"mylist": mylist}
```

**View (first attempt at converting queryset to list)**

```
test = User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True)
mylist = list(test)
context = {"mylist": mylist}
```

**View (second attempt at converting queryset to list to json)**

```
test = User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True)
mylist= json.dumps(list(test))
context = {"mylist": mylist}
```

**Template(with javascript)**

```
function usernameFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let text = '';
  let x = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;

  let listNames = {{mylist|safe}};
  //let listNames = ["john", "sid", "paul", "jim"];

  if ( listNames.includes(x.toLowerCase()) ) {
    text = x + ' allready taken.';
  }
  if (x === '' ||  x == null) {
    text = "Username cannot be blank";
  }

  if (text.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("username_errors").innerHTML = text;
    return false;
  }
  // trigger Submit programmatically
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  console.log('trigger submit')
}

document.addEventListener('invalid', (function () {
  return function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    document.getElementsByName("username").focus();

  };
})(), true);
```

What am I doing wrong in converting the queryset to a list for the javascript array to accept in the template?

Help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you please update full code of javascript template.

Comment: @ShashikamalRC I have updated with the full javascript code - please bear in mind this code works with the View (manual python list above which works and also you will notice commented out js list which also works. So I believe the underlying issue is with the django queryset not being recognised as a list by js. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change you `views.py`.

```
test = list(User.objects.filter(column_name='Value you want to fetch').values())
context = json.dumps({"mylist":test})
return render(request, "your JS location", context})
```

Use `escapejs` in your `Javascript`

`let listNames = {{mylist|escapejs}};`

Comment: Thanks for this, `test = list(User.objects.filter(column_name='Value you want to fetch').values())` I changed `column_name` to `username` and `=` to a user but this pulls all fields for a user and then `context = json.dumps({"mylist":test})` the error appears `Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable` . I'm only trying to pull all usernames in user model to feed through to JS. Moreover The js code becomes completely unresponsive when adding `{{mylist|escapejs}}`. I even tested with previous code normal python list which worked but adding  `{{mylist|escapejs}}`. breaks it.

Comment: ```json.dumps({"mylist":test}, default="")``` use this